# Consequences of lower bounds for $\epsilon$-nets on approximation

Tags: cg.comp-geom, set-cover, hypergraphs, approximation-hardness, epsilon-nets

Many here are probably aware of Alon's recent super-linear lower bounds for $\epsilon$-nets in a natural geometric setting [[PDF]](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/epsnet3.pdf).  I would like to know what, if anything, such a lower bound implies about the approximability of the associated Set Cover/Hitting Set problems.

To be slightly more specific, consider a family of range spaces, for example, the family:

$\big\{(X,\mathcal{R})$ : $X$ is a finite planar point set, $\mathcal{R}$ contains all intersections of $X$ with lines$\big\}$

If, for some function $f$ that is linear or super-linear, the family contains a range space that does not admit $\epsilon$-nets of size $f(1/\epsilon)$, what, if anything, does this imply about the Minimum Hitting Set problem restricted to this family of range spaces?

Comment: there's a new result out that has even stronger lower bounds: http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1240

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a range space has $\epsilon$-net of size $f(1/\epsilon)$, then the integrality gap of the fractional hitting set (or set cover) is $f(1/\epsilon)/(1/\epsilon)$. See the work by Philip Long ([here](http://www.phillong.info/publications/intprog.pdf) [The Even etal. work is later than this work, and rediscover some of his stuff]). See also the slides 13-16 [here](http://valis.cs.uiuc.edu/~sariel/papers/10/haystacks/haystack.pdf).

In short, having non-linear $\epsilon$-nets, indicates that approximating the relevant hitting-set/set cover problem within  better than a constant factor is going to be very challenging.

Comment: Which section of the first paper is relevant to this particular problem? Or equivalently, in the second link, you say "In geometric settings, there is an $\epsilon$-net of size $O(K/\epsilon)$ iff the integrality gap is $K$." I am having trouble understanding that.

Comment: Theorem 1 in the paper....

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure it does imply anything. The main results flow in the other direction i.e by the [Bronnimann/Goodrich](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~goodrich/cgc/pubs/cover.ps.gz) or [Even/Rawitz/Shahar](http://www.eng.tau.ac.il/~guy/Papers/VC.pdf) constructions, a linear sized net implies a constant factor approximation for the hitting set (for bounded VC dimension),